# Turning a pandas dataframe from Excel file (xlrd) to a list

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlrd

I am new to Python. I read data from an excel file. How may I turn the column into a list? The column is part of a pandas dataframe, read from an xlsx file by xlrd package. Any better way to solve the problem is also appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("MyData_XYZ.xlsx")
sheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

def get_cell_range2(sheet, start_col, start_row, end_col,  end_row):
    return [sheet.row_slice(row, start_colx=start_col-1, end_colx=end_col) for row in range(start_row-1, end_row)]

er_aaa = get_cell_range2(sheet1, 1, 2, 2,  67)
er_aaa_df = pd.DataFrame(er_aaa, columns= ['date', 'aaa'])
raw_seq = list(er_aaa_df['aaa'])
```

I got this in Spyder

```
raw_seq
Out[61]: 
0     number:25.405
1     number:25.427
2     number:25.411
3     number:25.423
4      number:25.45

61    number:26.054
62     number:26.09
63    number:26.103
64      number:26.1
65     number:26.03
Name: aaa, Length: 66, dtype: object
```

How can I turn the result to a simple list, namely,

```
[25.405, 25.427, 25.411, ...... 26.03]
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Try `pd.to_numeric(er_aaa_df['aaa'].str.extract('([\d\.]+)', expand=False), errors='coerce').tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to read data from xlsx and get one of its columns. You can get it such as below.

```
df = pd.read_excel("MyData_XYZ.xlsx")

list = df['aaa'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use: `data=pd.read_excel("MyData_XYZ.xlsx", header=1)`, see [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)
Then you can just select your values with `data['number']`. But carefull this is still a dataframe object, if you want a pure list, just do `list( data['number'])`